# 二つの DataFrame から条件に一致する重複データのみを抽出したい

Tags: python, pandas

下記のようにAとBのデータがあり、ひとつ前の要素と比較して、AもBも重複していたら、その要素のみを抽出したいと考えております。
この場合、A列の「A4」が抽出の対象となります。

[image: 配列のデータ]

下記のように `for` 文を使って記述してみましたが、重複のみを抽出することがうまくできませんでした。
ご教示いただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A11', 'A3'],
                    'B': [0, 1, 0, 4]},
                   index=[0, 1, 2, 3])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A4', 'A4', 'A7', 'A7'],
                    'B': [3, 3, 8, 7]},
                   index=[4, 5, 6, 7])

df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2])

for i in range(len(df3["A"])-1):
    for j in range(len(df3["B"])-1):
        if df3["A"][i] == df3["A"][i+1] and df3["B"][i] == df3["B"][i+1]:
            print(df3["B"][j])
```

Comment: 何か「お題」のようになってる雰囲気あるけど, 念の為 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: すみません。以後気を付けます。

Answer (score 1):

参考までに、for loop を使わない方法を紹介します。

```py
>>> df3[(df3 == df3.shift(1)).all(axis=1)]
    A  B
5  A4  3
```

[pandas.DataFrame.shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)
[pandas.DataFrame.all](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html)

Comment: 大変シンプルな記述で驚きました。うまく動きました。

Answer (score 0):

B の方の添字は j を使うべきではないでしょうか？

```
if df3["A"][i] == df3["A"][i+1] and df3["B"][j] == df3["B"][j+1]:
```

Comment: おっしゃる通りです。ご指摘の箇所を修正したら、うまく動きました。

Answer (score 0):

下記だとどうでしょうか？

```
for i in range(1, len(df3["A"])):
    if df3["A"][i] == df3["A"][i-1] and df3["B"][i] == df3["B"][i-1]:
        print(df3["A"][i])
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

`for`文なしのパターンです

```py
df3.groupby(['A','B']).filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 2)

#     A  B
# 4  A4  3
# 5  A4  3
```

Comment: `groupby()` を使うと例えば最初の行と最後の行が同じ場合でも抽出してしまいます。

Comment: それは気づきませんでした。(^^;;
これで大丈夫かな？

Comment: こちらの方法でもうまく動きました。
'.groupby'を使うのですね。大変勉強になりました。

Comment: @Nobutaro データが最初から昇順に並んでるような場合は, ソートのステップ `.sort_values(['A','B'])` は省けます。あと, データの纏め方は `groupby()` 以外にもあるかも (何にしても, 各ステップが理解できればそれで)

Comment: `groupby`はデフォルトでは内部で sortが行われるようなので, 元に戻しました。元の DataFrameである `df1`, `df2` が順番に並んでいるようなら, `groupby` に `sort=False`オプションで少しだけ高速になるかも